# Is there a way to prevent creating another if statement for different types?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to reduce all the if constexpr statements assuming the searching of the buffers is all the same behavior?

```
template <typename T>
struct Buffer
{};

struct BufferManager
{
    Buffer<int> intBuffers[8];
    Buffer<float> floatBuffers[8];
    Buffer<char> charBuffers[8];

    template <typename T>
    static void uploadBuffer(int size, const T* data)
    {
        Buffer<T>* buffer = findSuitableBuffer<T>(size);


    }

    template<typename T>
    static Buffer <T>* findSuitableBuffer(int size)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        {
            // SEARCH intBuffers FOR A SUITABLE BUFFER
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>)
        {
            // SEARCH floatBuffers FOR A SUITABLE BUFFER
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
        {
            // AND SO ON
        } // DO I HAVE TO ADD ONE OF THESE EACH TIME I WANT TO ADD A TYPE?

        Buffer<T> g{};
        return &g;
    }

};
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are returning address of a temporary at the end of function? Also, you want to search non-static member from within a static function. This would cause an error IMO.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to delete, I was getting rid of compiler errors, thank you.

Comment: If you have an `if`-`else` construct that is all about checking the type of something, you have a prime candidate for a polymorphic (non-template) base with (possibly) a templated class derived from that base and overriding inherited virtual member functions.

Comment: You can use `std::tuple` to store all your `<T>Buffers` data members and then you can use `std::get<T>(<your tuple member>)`. But probably you'll need to change your architecture a bit... in order to get the things right.

Comment: Do you really need 3 separate buffers to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the way you store your buffers, you can write a `findSuitableBuffer` that takes multiple heterogeneously typed buffers via a a recursive function variadic template...

```cpp
template <typename T>
Buffer<T>& findSuitableBufferImpl(size_t size) {
    throw std::runtime_error("not found");
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename...Ts, size_t I, size_t...Is>
Buffer<T>& findSuitableBufferImpl(size_t size, Buffer<U>(&buffer)[I], Buffer<Ts>(&...buffers)[Is]) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < I; i++) {
            if (/* test buffer[i] */) {
                return buffer[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return findSuitableBufferImpl<T>(size, buffers...);
}

template <typename T>
Buffer<T>& findSuitableBuffer(size_t size) {
    // Add types here
    return findSuitableBufferImpl<T>(size, intBuffers, floatBuffers, charBuffers);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/aYY4Ye

---

And, if you were able to use a tuple to store those buffers, it would take a small adjustment:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct BufferSet : std::tuple<Buffer<Ts>[8]...> {
    using std::tuple<Buffer<Ts>[8]...>::tuple;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
constexpr Buffer<T> findSuitableBufferImpl(size_t size, BufferSet<Ts...>& buffers, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return findSuitableBufferImpl<T>(size, std::get<Is>(buffers)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr Buffer<T> findSuitableBuffer(size_t size, BufferSet<Ts...>& buffers) {
    return findSuitableBufferImpl<T>(size, buffers, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}

// usage
BufferSet<int, double, char> buffers;
auto& buffer = findSuitableBuffer<double>(4, buffers);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/v7PzGc

Comment: Wow, that recursive example is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get rid of the `if constexpr` is to make specializations for `findSuitableBuffer` that returns the correct array of buffers. Another way is to skip `findSuitableBuffer` completely and store the buffers in a tuple.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>

struct BufferManager {
    static constexpr size_t kBuffers = 8;

    std::tuple<Buffer<int>[kBuffers],
               Buffer<float>[kBuffers],
               Buffer<char>[kBuffers]> Buffers;

    template <typename T>
    void uploadBuffer(const T* data, size_t size) {
        auto& buffers = std::get<Buffer<T>[kBuffers]>(Buffers);

        // SEARCH buffers FOR A SUITABLE BUFFER
        for(size_t i = 0; i < kBuffers; ++i) {
            if(buffers[i].has_room_for(size)) {
                // ...
            }
        }        
    }
};
```